# forgot my password which is needed for installation

Tags: password

**forgot my password which is needed for installation .cant download gnu plot now.
please rescue my password.**I tried so many times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reboot to recovery mode. At very first boot time hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, boot to recovery in grub menu, choose "drop to root shell", type in shell prompt:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

`passwd yourusername`
You will be asked for new password.
Then `reboot` and have fun.